# Can highly fragmented indexes cause CPU spike in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am seeing CPU spikes on database server everyday and I found out that indexes were not rebuilt for quite a while. Could it be a reason of those spikes?

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it is totally depend on the number of records available in that particular table, Fragmentation can cause CPU spike as well as 100% CPU utilization for server during load. 
Because while searching for pages by indexes during load, CPU have 4 milliseconds of quantum for query to execute, if the query executing on CPU required additional pages in the memory(which is not available in memory) due to fragmentation storage engine has to look back and forth in the B+ Tree where pages are scattered leading CPU hast to spill that query in the waiter list, once the data available it moves to the runnable queue(where query waiting for CPU to execute). 
Just imagine if the table having huge records then definitely fragmentation would have impact on CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Fragmentation might cause a little more CPU load but it does not cause spikes. Why would it? Look elsewhere. Find out what queries are running during the spikes, and look at long-running queries with lots of CPU.

Comment: I found queries and other stuff. I am curious about fragmentation.

Comment: Fragmentation of indexes can make queries perform slower.  Mostly increased IO from having to read more pages, partly increased CPU for having to process those additional pages.  If fragmentation is causing this you should first identify the queries using high CPU, then see if the CPU load is being exaggerated due to index fragmentation *(seems unlikely, but possible)* or some other cause.  *(An index in itself does not utilise the cpu, queries utilise cpu)*